# NODE Cannot GET routes function

Tags: node.js, angular2-routing, nodes, node-modules, node-webkit

I have created a folder **testint**
My testint/app.js having following code

```
const express = require('express');  const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');  const cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('passport');  const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();   const port = 7000;  app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/users', users); //Not working

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.send("Invalid Endpoint");
});

app.listen(port, () =>{
console.log('Server started on port '+ port);
});
```

testint/routes/users.js contains :

```
const express = require('express');   const router = express.Router();    
res.send('Authenticate');

    router.get('/register',(req, res, next) => {
            res.send('REGISTER');
    });        
    module.exports = router;
```

If I run http://localhost:7000/users/register

Am getting :
**Cannot GET /users/register**

I dint know where am wrong and am new to node any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like `users` is not required in `testint/app.js`!

Comment: @explorer I removed but not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution. I didn't include

```
const users = require('./routes/users');
```

in app.js

and res.send('Authenticate'); in users.js is not required for instance.